# AVPlayer is playing my m3u file only when the file is not on the local device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer, m3u

I would like to play a ts video file. The only simple way to do it is to save the ts url under an m3u file. That's what i did. The problem now is that AVPlayer don't play anything when i have this m3u file on my device. It plays it only when the file is saved on the web. I don't understand where is the problem..

Here is my code :

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.m3u",(long)indexPath.row];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *publicDocumentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [publicDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath];
[AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];

[avPlayer play];
```

If i change

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.m3u",(long)indexPath.row];
```

with

```
NSString* fileName = @"http://www.media.com/url.m3u";
```

It will work fine...

Anyone to help me before i loose all my hairs?

Comment: Anything interesting in your log?

Comment: No, when i added an observer for the avplayer.status, always ok.

Comment: I'd start by cutting all that filename generation code out. Call the local file `url.m3u` and try loading that the same way.

Comment: I tried. Not working. It seems that the app is maybe not finding the file even if i can read the content?! Maybe it's a simulator problem... I'll try on my apple tv..

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. could you solve it ?